# How to make columns using a linktable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
packs: pack_id, packtype_id
packtypes: packtype_id, packtype_name
levels: level_id, level_name
levels_in_packtype: level_id, packtype_id
```

Now I want to display all "packs" in a grid. Packs have no name, they are identified by what packtype and levels they have:

```
birdpack | USA | California 
birdpack | Sweden | Norrland
```

(birdpack is a packtype, usa and california are levels)

or

```
temppack | Sweden | Norrland | Umea
```

(sweden, norrland and umea are levels)

Question: How to write a query so I get a dataset that have columns for all levels that belong to a pack?

I use Postgres.

Comment: Please, first add the real DDL to your question, including primary and foreign keys. This shorthand is unreadable, IMHO

Comment: In addition to the DDL, can you also add some sample input data and desired output?